# Construct a line through 2 circles with equal length in each circle going through a common point

Tags: geometry, euclidean-geometry

> Given two circles intersecting at $P$ and another point. Construct a line through $P$ such that: If $B$ and $C$ are the intersections of the line with the first circle and the second circle then $|BP| = |PC|$.

I was able to demonstrate the existence of such a line easily by intermediate value theorem, but I am stuck now, hints?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let $O_1$ and $O_2$ be centers of our circles and let $C$ be a midpoint of $O_1O_2$.

Now, let $l$ passes trough $P$ such that $l\perp CP$ and intersects our circles in points $A$ and $B$.

Prove that $AP=BP$.

Good luck!

Comment: [+1]. Clever solution!